# What should i do to stick the footer to be always at the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-rest-framework

I followed [this](https://dev.to/nehalahmadkhan/how-to-make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-web-page-3i14) tutorial to create a footer.

And i created a footer like this(without any content in body):

```css
 
body{

    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
   
}  
footer{
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

.card {
  
  max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  position:  relative;
  top: 611px;
  margin-bottom: 33px; 
  margin-right: 33px;
  float: left;
  
  
}

 




.card img{

  height: 400px; 
    width: 400px;
  vertical-align: middle;
 
 
}

.price {background-color: #f44336;
    font-size:22px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 3px;




}

.card button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative ;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 44px;
  align-items: center;



  


}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  background-color: #330;


}
 

#id{
    background-color: palevioletred;
    color: white;   
    margin: 0; 
    font-size: 17px;
}
 
 
.number{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #330;
    color: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
    right: -22px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 22px;

}

 

@media  (max-width: 1864px){
    .card{
        max-width: 300px;
    }
     
    .price{

        font-size:20px;

    }

    .card img{
        height: 300px; 
        width: 300px;



}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
    <h1>header</h1>
    
</head>
<body style="background-color: #36454F;">



 
    <footer class="footer">
        <h3 >hello</h3>

    </foote>     

</body>
</html>
```

i added some contents to the body of html like this in django with for loop:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
    <h1>header</h1>
    
</head>
<body style="background-color: #36454F;">




    {% for i in p%} 
 
                <div class='card'>
                    <div class="number">{{i.Number}}</div>
                    <img src="{{i.image}}"></img>
                    <p id="id">{{i.description}}</p>
                    <a href="{{i.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                        <button><span class="price"> ${{i.price}}</span> buy</button>
                    </a>    




                </div>



 
    {%endfor%}

    <footer class="footer">
        <h3 >hello</h3>
        
    </foote>     

</body>
</html>
```

But the footer is in not at the bottom of the web page:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Ctv.png)

What should i do to stick the footer to be always at the bottom of the products?

Comment: Hi! please try this   body {  margin-bottom: 0;}

Comment: First complete footer end  tag </footer> insted of </foote>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container with `position: relative; min-height: 100vh;` and a footer with `position: absolute` as follows:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* Height of the footer */
}

.content {
  height: 50px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

For longer content, it would look like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* Height of the footer */
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not forget to set container padding-bottom to the height of footer, if you don't, then the footer and content might overlap. Also mayble  good idea to always do initial css reset like: * {padding: 0; margin: 0} which eliminates white lines surrounding all the content and gives you a bit more control

Comment: Sure! I added that but removed it later to make it simpler. But yeah, it makes more sense to add it.

Answer (score -1):

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think he meant at the bottom of the page, not fixed to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}


.body{
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 12rem;
}
```